# how to call internal method by external function 'vue.js 2'

Tags: javascript, vue.js

What can I do to make this work?

I'd like to do something like this in 'vue.js 2'
What's the correct way?

```
<script>
var app = new Vue({
    el: "#app",

    data: {
        config: []
    },

    methods: {
        addLine: function() {
            alert();
        }
    }
});


//I'd like to do something like this in vue.js 2
app.addLine();
//But it doesn't work
//What's the correct way?
```

Comment: That [works](https://codepen.io/Kradek/pen/BJvOBO?editors=1010). There must be a different issue in code you haven't posted.

Comment: There is a possibility that browser can try to invoke method before vue app is created.

Comment: Why would you ever want to do something like that? Other than that - I agree with @ElDanielo Vue instance might get instantiated a bit later. Check the [lifecycle diagram](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/instance.html) on the official page to add hooks ;)